# Pythonic way to select element in a list window

Tags: python

Here is a list where I would like to keep only the 'windows' where there are a group of number higher than 3, but if in any case inside this group you find a smaller number, you keep it.

Moreover, if there is an isolated high number (between zeros for example), we need to delete it.

```
l = [3.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 4, 10, 20, 3, 20, 10, 2, 0, 0, 3.5, 0, 2, 18, 15, 2, 14, 2, 0]
```

and the expected result :

```
[4, 10, 20, 3, 20, 10, 18, 15, 2, 14]
```

This program does it but I feel this it not very pythonic, could you think of any other way ?

```
l = [3.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 4, 10, 20, 3, 20, 10, 2, 0, 0, 3.5, 0, 2, 18, 15, 2, 14, 2, 0]

new_l = []
index = []
seuil = 3

for i, elt in enumerate(l):
    if elt > seuil: 
        if (l[i-1] and l[i+1]) > 1: 
            new_l.append(elt)
            index.append(i)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        try: 
            if (l[i-1] and l[i+1]) > seuil: 
                new_l.append(elt)
                index.append(i)
        except IndexError:
            pass
print index
print new_l
```

Comment: Do you actually need the `index` list? It is not used in the code itself.

Comment: Yes, I need the `index` list only actually. The `new_l` is only to check if the process goes well.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean by a "window", and why the expected result is what you say it should be? I strongly suspect that the code you wrote doesn't actually do what you intend.

Comment: I mean by window that if you have more than 3 following numbers that are higher than the threshold, you keep it. Maybe it's not written the best way but it does what I need. If you have better idea, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write functions, improvements can range from [faster code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11241523) to the ability to reliably time or profile your code.
2. You don't need to use `else` if you're just using `pass` in that block.
3. Your code is WET, so it's not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Instead of duplicating the code, you could instead assign to a variable in the `if` and `else`, to check against.
4. You may want to get into a habit of using [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163). In short, if you import the file it won't run the code.

This can get you:

```
def rename_me(l, seuil):
    new_l = []
    index = []
    for i, elt in enumerate(l):
        bound = 1 if elt > seuil else seuil
        try:
            if (l[i-1] and l[i+1]) > bound:
                new_l.append(elt)
                index.append(i)
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return index, new_l
```

---

A couple more things:

- I think you have a bug, `(l[i-1] and l[i+1]) > bound` probably isn't doing what you think it is. It's only checking if `l[i+1]` is greater than `bound`. As `1 and 2 == 2` and `0 and 2 == 0` are both true. Instead you may want to use `l[i-1] > bound < l[i+1]`.
- I don't see why you'd need the indexes and the elements from the original list, and so you could instead just return one or the other.
- You can change the function to be a generator function, as this reduces memory usage.
- You could use a modified [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), to remove the `IndexError`.

```
from itertools import tee

def rename_me(l, seuil):
    a, b, c = tee(l, 3)
    next(b, None)
    next(c, None)
    next(c, None)
    for index, (i, j, k) in enumerate(zip(a, b, c), 1):
        if i > (1 if j > seuil else seuil) < k:
            yield index
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. One question : what do you call a generator function ?

Comment: @Annabelle I assume you mean how do you call it, to get a list from it you can do `list(rename_me(l, seuil))`, but it's almost the same as `range` in Python 3 or `xrange` in Python 2